# Program 'node.exe' failed to run in visual studio code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

When I run node code in CMD it's perfectly working but in VS code terminal there's an error

```
> PS D:\MyApps\NodeSession> npm -v 6.4.1
> PS D:\MyApps\NodeSession> node -v
```

> 'node.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:1 + node -v + ~~~~~~~. 
>   At line:1 char:1 + node -v + ~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo :
>   ResourceUnavailable: (:) [] , ApplicationFailedException +
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

What should I do to run node in VS Code?

Comment: Is the cmd process running as admin? I'm wondering if you need to fix your NodeJS installation to run without admin rights.

Comment: I am just asking when I run node.js code in CMD it is working But VS code terminal it is not working????

Comment: I'm trying to help and understand better. [Is CMD running as Administrator (see image link)](https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fmk0intowindows84fvao.kinstacdn.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F03%2FCommand-Prompt-as-administrator.png&f=1)? "Access denied" sounds like NodeJS might have been installed in a location with admin-only access.

Comment: no CMD running as Administrator..

Comment: my input like this

PS D:\MyApps\NodeSession> npm -v
6.4.1
PS D:\MyApps\NodeSession> node -v
Program 'node.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt
line:1 char:1
+ node -v
+ ~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ node -v
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) []
   , ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

Answer (score 4):

May be your firewall is blocking the Powershell. Try to change the terminal type from the drop down in VS code and check whether it is working. Then you can get the idea whether it is associate with Powershell blocking.

Comment: thank you.Firewall blocked powershell that's the reason. So I change terminal type.

Comment: Good idea thinking to change the terminal type! Could you help me understand how firewall would affect Powershell here? @LasalSenarath if you switch back to Powershell terminal, do you still get the same error?

Comment: I think there some restrictions in my PC. So same error appear using powershell. My issue is overcome when changing CMD

Answer (score 0):

"Access denied" means the embedded Powershell terminal in VS Code found the node executable but it doesn't have permission to run it. Check the permissions on your node installation, and if necessary you may want to try uninstalling and reinstalling [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).

Comment: I reinstall the node.js but it won't work. still issue remaining