# How to solve "Program 'npm.cmd' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:1" error in Intellij?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm, intellij-idea, access-denied

I installed "node" and "npm" on Windows 10. I check the installation using following commands and it's all fine.

```
c:\>node -v
v16.17.0

c:\>npm -v
8.15.0
```

When I try to run the following command in the "IntelliJ" terminal I get an error.

```
PS D:\Cypress> npm init
Program 'npm.cmd' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:1
+ npm init 
+ ~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ npm init
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: The same applies when I run the "npm init" command in "VSCode" terminal.

Comment: looks like a permissions issue. Please check possible solutions here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57121928/program-node-exe-failed-to-run-in-visual-studio-code. I can also suggest choosing `cmd.exe` as a terminal in WebStorm (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2022.2/terminal-emulator.html#application-settings) instead of `powershell`

Comment: Thank you @lena! Changing terminal type actually worked. I created new terminals of type "Command Prompt" in both "IntelliJ" and "VSCode" and they both worked.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @lena I created new terminals of type `Command Prompt` in both `IntelliJ` and `VSCode` and they both worked. It seems that firewall was blocking `powrshell` so changing the terminal type from `powershell` to `Command Prompt` worked.