# Program 'npm.cmd' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:1

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I was trying to run some TestCafe code in Visual Studio Code. I am getting the below error when I give commands to run.

```
Program 'node.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:515
+ ... 3e5949f"}'; & 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe' '--no-deprecation' ' ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:515
+ ... 3e5949f"}'; & 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe' '--no-deprecation' ' ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

The thing is this test script was working fine with my other machine.

Alos, the Visual Studio Code does not allow me to do `npm install --save-dev` to install anything new. It gives the following error.

```
Program 'npm.cmd' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:1
+ npm install --save-dev flow-bin
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ npm install --save-dev flow-bin
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve "Program 'npm.cmd' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:1" error in Intellij?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73698201/how-to-solve-program-npm-cmd-failed-to-run-access-is-deniedat-line1-char1)

Comment: I don't know how to change access for the powershell. Can you explain that?

Comment: Rather look into how to change the default profile. If you don't specify anything, Powershell is  assumed. You can set `cmd.exe` by adding this to your `settings.json`: `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt"` (or changing the value if it exists already).

Comment: I got some progress after following your instruction and now I have the following error. `ERROR Error: Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -NoLogo -NonInteractive -Command $cp = (C:\Windows\System32\chcp.com | Select-String '\d+').Matches.Value; Try { C:\Windows\System32\chcp.com 65001; Get-Item 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\*\shell\open\command'|Get-ItemProperty -Name '(default)'|Format-List -Property '(default)','PSPath'|Out-String -Width 2147483647|Write-Host; }`

Comment: Seems like VSCode is still trying to launch PowerShell instead of cmd. What happens if you open a new integrated terminal? Does it open PowerShell or cmd?

Comment: Its cmd. I have changed the `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows` settings again into PowerShell and checked the terminal. Then it opens as PowerShell but getting the previous error again.

Answer (score 0):

Step to resolve this error.
Program 'npm.cmd' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:1

- npm start
- 

At line:1 char:1

- npm start
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
  ```

1. go to search system variable.
2. environment variable.
3. in system variable remove ComSpec variable completely.
4. go and check npm start.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).